# Problem connecting with D-link DWM-221 LTE not work

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, usb, hardware

Has anyone managed to use the D-Link DWM-221 modem?

Serial interface does not appear for use by Wvdial.

cat /var/log/message

```
Dec 19 11:40:19 host kernel: [  528.228583] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
Dec 19 11:40:19 host kernel: [  528.330248] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=2001, idProduct=a406
Dec 19 11:40:19 host kernel: [  528.330259] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Dec 19 11:40:19 host kernel: [  528.330266] usb 1-1.4: Product: Mobile Connect
Dec 19 11:40:19 host kernel: [  528.330272] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Mobile Connect
Dec 19 11:40:19 host kernel: [  528.330278] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
Dec 19 11:40:19 host kernel: [  528.332393] usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Dec 19 11:40:19 host kernel: [  528.332803] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.329168] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access              SD Storage       0000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.333260] scsi 0:0:0:1: CD-ROM                     Mass Storage     0000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.333768] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.333780] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x5 [current] 
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.333788] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x20 ASCQ=0x0 
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.335146] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.335162] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x5 [current] 
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.335171] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x20 ASCQ=0x0 
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.335352] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.335558] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.337256] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.337278] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x5 [current] 
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.337286] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x20 ASCQ=0x0 
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.342613] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.342870] scsi 0:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.349262] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.349280] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x5 [current] 
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.349287] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x20 ASCQ=0x0 
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.350575] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.350983] sr 0:0:0:1: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
Dec 19 11:40:20 host kernel: [  529.351002] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
```

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2001:a406 D-Link Corp.
```

affter eject /dev/sr0

cat /var/log/message

```
Dec 19 11:43:07 host kernel: [  696.972956] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 5
Dec 19 11:43:07 host kernel: [  696.975862] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Dec 19 11:43:07 host kernel: [  696.975981] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
Dec 19 11:43:08 host kernel: [  697.288652] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
Dec 19 11:43:08 host kernel: [  697.392713] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=2001, idProduct=7e19
Dec 19 11:43:08 host kernel: [  697.392727] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Dec 19 11:43:08 host kernel: [  697.392733] usb 1-1.4: Product: Mobile Connect
Dec 19 11:43:08 host kernel: [  697.392739] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Mobile Connect
Dec 19 11:43:08 host kernel: [  697.392745] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
Dec 19 11:43:08 host kernel: [  697.397340] usb-storage 1-1.4:1.5: USB Mass Storage device detected
Dec 19 11:43:08 host kernel: [  697.397545] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1.4:1.5
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.389539] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access              SD Storage       0000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.390355] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.396308] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.396324] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x5 [current] 
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.396331] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x20 ASCQ=0x0 
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.398219] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.398229] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x5 [current] 
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.398237] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x20 ASCQ=0x0 
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.398619] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.402715] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.405537] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.405552] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x5 [current] 
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.405559] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x20 ASCQ=0x0 
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.408109] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.408121] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x5 [current] 
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.408129] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x20 ASCQ=0x0 
Dec 19 11:43:09 host kernel: [  698.413304] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2001:7e19 D-Link Corp.
```

ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*

```
ls: cannot access /dev/ttyUSB*: No such file or directory
```

dpkg -l usb-modeswitch*

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                        Version            Architecture       Description
+++-===========================-==================-==================-============================================================
rc  usb-modeswitch              2.2.0+repack0-2    armhf              mode switching tool for controlling "flip flop" USB devices
rc  usb-modeswitch-data         20150115-1         all                mode switching data for usb-modeswitch
un  usb-modeswitch-data-packed  <none>             <none>             (no description available)
```

quero fazer a comunicação com Wvdial, mas não consigo.
Help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally, I was able to switch the D-Link DWM-221 modem.**

Here's the step-by-step:

**1** - Check the version of usb_modeswitch

```
usb_modeswitch --version
```

If it is less than 2.5. * Follow the steps and install the latest version at http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/#download

**2** - Plug the modem into the USB port

**3** - Mount the /dev/sr0 media drive

```
mount /dev/sr0 /media
```

**4** - Inside the mounted partition has the file DTLW1_D600B_linux_1.0.2VI_140515.tar.gz, unzip and run install.sh

```
./install.sh
```

5 - Use the following command to make the modem switch

```
usb_modeswitch -v 2001 -p a406 -V 2001 -7e19 -K -W
```

Ready, switched modem, you can check with the command ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*

```
ls -l / dev / ttyUSB *
crw-rw ---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Jun 28 14:53 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw ---- 1 root dialout 188, 1 Jun 28 14:53 /dev/ttyUSB1
crw-rw ---- 1 root dialout 188, 2 Jun 28 14:53 /dev/ttyUSB2
crw-rw ---- 1 root dialout 188, 3 Jun 28 14:53 /dev/ttyUSB3
crw-rw ---- 1 root dialout 188, 4 Jun 28 14:53 /dev/ttyUSB4
```

:)